# Prove that $f(x)=x^{2}$ continuous at 2

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Please check my proof

First I set up $|f(x)-f(c)|=|x^{2}-4|=|x-2||x+2|$

then $let \epsilon >0 $and$\delta >0$

now we have

$$|x-2|<\delta \leftrightarrow |x-2|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$$

and

$$|x-2|<\delta \leftrightarrow |x+2|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$$

then     $$\leftrightarrow |x-2||x+2|<\sqrt{\epsilon }\sqrt{\epsilon }=\epsilon $$
therefore it is continuous at $ 2 $

Comment: Sorry to bring this; but the passage does not prove anything. The task is to find, for each $\varepsilon > 0$, a upper bound $\delta$ for $|x-2|$ such that $|x^{2}-2^{2}| < \varepsilon$ for all $x$ in the ball of center $2$ and radius $\delta$. You might want to try again,

Comment: Try assuming that $|x-1|<1$ (i.e. $\delta=1$) and you should find you can bound the $|x+1|$ term. Then you can bound $|x-1|$ with $\epsilon$. You then require the minimum of the two values so that both bounds on $|x-1|$ are satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Since we are interested in the behavior of $f$ near $2$ we can assume that $0<x<3$. Then

$|f(x)-f(2)|=|x-2|*|x+2| = |x-2|(x+2) \le 5|x-2|$.

Your turn !

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is somewhat confused. What you have to prove is that given $\epsilon$ there's a $\delta$...

Then you can't start off by assuming $\epsilon>0$ **and** $\delta>0$.

However your calculations are not i vein. Your approach is to prove that if $|x-2|<\sqrt\epsilon$ then $|x^2-4|<\epsilon$ (not exactly true, but we will fix that too). This means that given an $\epsilon>0$ we know there is an $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$ such that whenever $|x-2|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$.

To fix it you have to realize that $|x-2|<\sqrt\epsilon$ does **not** mean $|x+2|<\sqrt\epsilon$ (take for example $x=2$ and see that $|x+2|=4$). What you instead do is to limit the range and estimate $|x+2|$ otherway. If you also require that $4>x>0$ we have that $0<|x+2|<4$.

So if we pick $\delta$ acordingly so that $\delta<2$ (which means that $|x-2|<2$ which meanst that $4>x>0$).

$$|x^2-4| = |x-2||x+2| < 4|x-2| < 4\delta $$

Almost there. Now we also need to have $4\delta<\epsilon$ and then the we would have $|f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$. But that we can get by also requiring that $\delta < \epsilon/4$.

So given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta = \min(2,\epsilon/4)$ such that whenever $|x-2|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$. Which is what we had to prove.